# ctmconv, zenity and filenames with spaces

Tags: bash, zenity

I'm making a little conversion script in Zenity, but have noticed that ctmconv won't allow spaces in a filename.
Can I get rid of spaces in the input filename?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop
file="$(zenity --title "3D Converter:         Select a File to convert" --file-selection --file-filter=""*.ctm" "*.ply" "*.stl" "*.3ds" "*.dae" "*.obj" "*.lwo" "*.off"")"
filetype=$(zenity --list --title="Select File Type" --text="file types\ selection" --column="Select" --column="File Type" --radiolist false 3ds false ctm false dae false lwo false obj false off false ply true stl false wrl)
szSavePath="$(zenity --file-selection --filename="${file%%."${file##*.}"}"."$filetype" --save --confirm-overwrite)"
# szSavePath="$(zenity --file-selection --filename="out"."$filetype" --save --confirm-overwrite)"
ctmconv "$file" $szSavePath
zenity --info --text "Conversion Completed"
```

The above script gets the file to be converted, then asks for the filetype to convert to.
It then replaces the original filetype with the new one and passes the result to ctmconv.
Probably a messy way to do it, but hey ho! I'm new to this.

ctmconv just falls over if "$file" is "model rail", but is fine if it is just "model"

Comment: Does it still fail if you do something like `ctmconv model\ rail.obj model\ rail2.ply` .I don't have `ctmconv` or any sample files so it would be hard for me to test. Also, have you read the man page for `ctmconv` ? Maybe it has suggestions for it

Comment: Also, `"$file"` is properly quoted, which is good, but you didn't quote `$szSavePath` that could be an issue there as well.

Comment: Now then!  Just typing in the command line "ctmconv model\ rail.obj model\ rail2.ply" worked perfectly.  So that's a start....  And yes, I shall amend it to "$szSavePath".  What should I do next?

Comment: Your `--file-filter` quoting is a bit off. Why is there a `""` at the start?

Comment: If I use only one quote at either end, the filter doesn't work for some reason..  I only get the first choice (.ctm) appearing.

Answer (score 0):

For some very odd reason , `ctmconv` doesn't recognize quoted variables as one entity if their contents contain spaces. (Which may also be a worthwhile to report this behavior as a bug to the developers).

I suggest you use any text-editing tool , such as `sed` or `awk` to insert backslash before space. For instance, something like this.

```
$ echo "with space" | sed 's/\ /\\ /g'                                         
with\ space
```

In case of your variable, something like this will do:

```
$ file="with space"
$ file="$( echo $file | sed 's/\ /\\ /g'  )"
$ echo "$file"
with\ space
```

Comment: So I've got:    `nfile="$(echo $file | sed 's/\ /\\ /g'  )"
echo "$file"
echo "$nfile"
ctmconv "$nfile" "$szSavePath"
zenity --info --text "Conversion Completed" `  and now I get ctmconv saying it can't find Model\ Rail.stl,  So I haven't quite got it yet.  Nor have I got the Edit comments here right either.. Sorry.

Comment: How about if you leave `$nfile` in `ctmconv ...` line unquoted in this case ?

Comment: Going fron .stl to .ctm, it looks like I now get the "output" as an error.  But it's close...    `Error: Invalid argument: /home/alistair/Desktop/Model Rail.ctm`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get the hang of commenting.  I can't post the code as it's too long, I can't upload it.  I can't eveng get a new line on it, so I have to answer my own question

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Desktop
file="$(zenity --title "3D Converter:         Select a File to convert" --file-selection --file-filter=""*.ctm" "*.ply" "*.stl" "*.3ds" "*.dae" "*.obj" "*.lwo" "*.off"")"
file="$( echo $file | sed 's/\ /\\ /g'  )"
filetype=$(zenity --list --title="Select File Type" --text="file types\ selection" --column="Select" --column="File Type" --radiolist false 3ds false ctm false dae false lwo false obj false off false ply true stl false wrl)
szSavePath="$(zenity --file-selection --filename="${file%%."${file##*.}"}" --save --confirm-overwrite)"
echo ctmconv $file $szSavePath."$filetype"
ctmconv $file $szSavePath."$filetype"
zenity --info --text "Conversion Completed"`
```

I just put echo ctmconv etc.  so you don't need ctmconv to see the output if you execute in a terminal..

```
ctmconv /home/alistair/Desktop/plastic/Buffers/Model\ Rail.stl /home/alistair/Desktop/Model\ Rail.3ds
Error: Invalid argument: /home/alistair/Desktop/Model\`
```

ctmconv falls down trying to output the file: the input is accepted.

But if I copy, paste and execute the "echo"ed line, it works perfectly....

What if I could just remove the spaces from the szSaveFile.  Could that be done?